# Output not displaying results that I am searching from myphpadmin

Tags: python, html, mysql

page.html is my first page where you search for users by name or a specific letter, you click the submit button which leads you to the search.py page. The py page should display all users from myphpadmin's table that was in the search bar. Currently my code is not displaying any users from the search bar and I am not sure why. My sql has been tested and is working fine.

search.py code

[image: search.py code]

page.html file

[image: page.html file]

result after clicking the "submit" button

[image: result after clicking the "submit" button]

Comment: Welcome. Please post code as _text_, not as an image. Thanks

Comment: Did the proposed answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `LIKE` to query your dataset and not searching for an exact record, you should include wildcards (`%`) to assist your search. Your sql should be like

```sql
SELECT * FROM table01 WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE "%e%"
```

and in your python code you may add the first line in your `search_by` code to make this adjustment

```py
text = "%{}%".format(text)
```

After completing this you may do some more research into sql injection